# Can I pass in an array for rest parameter?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that accepts a rest parameter.

```
function getByIds(...ids: string){
...
}
```

I know I can call `getByIds('andrew')` and `getByIds('andrew','jackson')` and it will convert the strings into an array of strings.

My question is: can I call `getByIds(['andrew','jackson'])`, if I already have the parameters merged into an array?

In Java I know I could, but typescript seems to give me problems. JsFiddle fails me too.

Comment: `script seems to give me problems` <= what is the error you are getting or what is it you are observing?

Comment: Did you trying using good-old `apply`?

Comment: FWIW, how do you define the function (i.e. with a rest parameter) is irrelevant actually.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, you can use the spread operator:

```
getByIds(...['andrew', 'jackson']);
```

It compiles to:

```
getByIds.apply(void 0, ['andrew', 'jackson']);
```

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that this doesn't (directly) assign the array to the rest parameter (the `...` have nothing to do with each other). So if the function signature was `function foo(a, ...b){}`, `'andrew'` would be assigned to `a` and `['jackson']` would be assigned to `b`.

Comment: @FelixKling If that was the signature, then you change it to: `getByIds("string", ...['andrew', 'jackson'])`

Comment: That wasn't my point... my point was that `...['andrew', 'jackson']` has nothing to do with `...ids`. Given that you said "yeah, you can" and the question is *"Can I pass in an array for rest parameter?"*, developers less familiar with JavaScript might be confused by that.

Comment: @FelixKling Well, that's why I included in my answer the compiled js of this approach. The js code doesn't use the spread operator...  I changed my answer a bit.